# JS not working/loading when not using an online editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code that works as expected on online editors (jsfiddle / codepen / jsbin etc) however, once I take it off of these and onto a live environment - or even a static index.html file, the js doesn't seem to be loading. This means the carousel module on the right isn't showing. Do you think it's something to do with the order of the css at the top?

https://jsfiddle.net/tLqhsr5j/

code that's not rendering:

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items: 2,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    navContainer: '#nav',
    navText: [
        '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
    ],
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        767:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        }
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The jsFiddle is set up to run your JS code in `onload`, which means if you haven't done the same / included your code's `<script>` at the top, the carousel HTML doesn't exist yet when the code is called.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it inside a document ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items: 2,
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    navContainer: '#nav',
    navText: [
        '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
    ],
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        767:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If in `JSFiddle` you can also select **`Javascript`** > **`Load Type`** > **`No wrap - bottom of <body>`**

Comment: hey! thanks, but I've added your js and it's still not loading on the index file? my link in the head is <script src="js.js"></script> - should it be something else?